SDL_Init() segfaults after somehow calling my close() function?
Why does this code:
/* gcc test.c -o test -lSDL2 -Wall -Wextra */
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

void close() {
    printf("HERE\n");
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    return 0;
}

...cause a segfault after printing multiple times "HERE"? Is the close function defined in sdl and called during the init?
I compiled it on archlinux, if i remove the close function or rename it works fine.

close() is a function in the Linux standard libraries, which you should not redefine. I'm surprised the linker didn't complain though.

close is a standard POSIX function, used to close an open file descriptor. By naming your function close, you're overriding that function.
The signature for close is:
int close(int fildes);

which your function doesn't match (and if it did match, it'd have to replicate/wrap close correctly).

SDL_Quit calls close, as do 3 other SDL functions.  You're going into a recursive call and running out of stack.  The correct way to do this, if you want to trace the SDL closes is
/* gcc test.c -o test -lSDL2 -Wall -Wextra */
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

void close() {
    printf("HERE\n");
}

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

